# PHP - check if image is fully uploaded through CURL, before trying to open it in another script

Tags: php, image, curl

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

**Sending image from Server 1 to Server 2 - check if image is completley transfered before opening it on Server 2**

Basically, Server 1 uploads an image(with the same name ever time) to Server 2. Server 2 uses that image to do something such as displaying it. The problem is that I want to detect if Server 1 is still uploading the image, before Server 2 tries to access that image as Server 2 does not want to show a corrupted image.

I was thinking of using a flip/flop scheme - where I always keep 2 images on Server 2, and if server 1 is uploading image1, then Server 2 will display image2, or vise-versa. Problem is that I need to detect if the image is still uploading.

Comment: Do you've any reference in server 2 for the image coming from server 1?

Comment: server 2 has no reference of anything coming from server 1. It only knows that there is an image in a folder somewhere in it's space(Server 2's space, that is).

Answer (score 0):

I frequently face this problem when uploading files via FTP...

The best "solution" I can come up with is to check `filemtime` on the file on Server 2. If the file was modified in the last second, then it's in the middle of being uploaded so `sleep(1)` and try again (or serve your flip/flop image instead)

Comment: Wouldn't the timing vary though? Depending on the uploading speed, it could very well vary, especially with images of size > 200kb (asuming low average speed of 200kbs upload)